# Manager isn't accessible via SocialToken instances

Tags: django, django-allauth

Something very weird is happening with my script, I've been debugging all day and haven't gotten anywhere. I've searched far and wide and nothing solved my issue, the title might be misleading but that's the error I get.

I'm using django-allauth, I have SocialAccounts and SocialTokens

```
    socialaccounts = SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='facebook')
    for SocialAccount in socialaccounts:
        socialtokens = SocialToken.objects.filter(id=SocialAccount.id)
        for SocialToken in socialtokens:
            #get a few values, set a few values
            #at the end update or create a custom model
            obj, created = FacebookPagesList.objects.update_or_create(user=P.user, Page_ID=P.Page_ID, uid=P.uid, defaults = updated_values)
```

I have debugged this several times, it works fine when it runs just once, IE I limit the SocialAccount list with a user filter for one user and it works properly, then I do it for the 2nd user and it works fine too. So far the 2 users are the only ones in the db. When I remove the user filter it goes through the 1st user and populates the model, but fails on the 2nd user.

idk what else to try. Here is my model.

```
class FacebookPagesList(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(SocialAccount)
Page_ID = models.CharField('Page ID', max_length=255)
Page_Name = models.CharField('Page Name', max_length=255)
Page_Access_Token = models.TextField('Page Token')
Page_Category = models.CharField('Page Category', max_length=100)
uid = models.CharField('FB User ID',max_length=255)
Perms = models.TextField('Permissions')
getdata = models.BooleanField('Pull data?', default=True, null=False)
DateAdded = models.DateTimeField('Date Added', default=timezone.now)
DateModified = models.DateTimeField('Date Modified', default=timezone.now)
LastDataPull = models.DateTimeField('Last Data Pulled', default='1990-01-01 00:00:00')
#id = models.IntegerField('ID', default=0, primary_key=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Page_Name

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'Page_ID')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you quite a bit. "Manager" refers to `Model.objects`, so somewhere you're trying to access `.objects` on a single `SocialToken`.

My guess is that somewhere in your code you have something like the following:

```
SocialToken = SocialToken.objects.first()  # This isn't good!
...
tokens = SocialToken.objects.all()  # This will cause your error
```

Here, because `SocialToken` refers to an instance rather than your model, you won't be able to access `SocialToken.objects`, your manager.

You've done this with `SocialAccount` in the code you pasted above. Use something like `social_account` rather than `SocialAccount` to refer to an individual account:

```
social_accounts = SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='facebook')
for social_account in social_accounts:
    socialtokens = SocialToken.objects.filter(id=social_account.id)
```

Go through your code and see if you have any `CapWords` instances and rename them so they're `separated_with_underscores`. See [the Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) for more information on class/instance/variable naming conventions (it's a good read!).

Comment: That totally worked. I didn't know python was able to tell social_account is a singular social_accounts. IDK what I'm trying to say really but I thought I had to look for the model in my for for it work. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped. Python isn't magically figuring out that `social_account` is an item in `social_accounts`: we're telling it to be. We could even say `for x in social_accounts...`, but that isn't as readable. Sticking to a naming convention can help a lot in the long run!